# How to handle jupyter notebook files in Ubuntu?

Tags: launcher, mime-type, jupyter

Recently the project jupyter [added](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/commit/d16367f70c28dc7b332ddc117ada4ba1dbebe45f) the mime-type to the ipynb files: `application/x-ipynb+json`, and I'd like to launch easily these files without having to allways launch the terminal command:

```
cd /path/to/notebook
jupyter notebook
```

So I've adapted this blog [post](https://termueske.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/a-hack-for-ipython-notebook/) in order to:

- launch a jupyter-notebook server when **double clicking** a `ipynb` file
- add **icon** to `ipynb` files.
- create a **desktop Launcher** to easily launch a jupyter notebook from a default folder or **dragging and dropping** a file or folder.

Here's how it looks, and see my answer below to understand how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. Create a `ipynb.xml` mime-info file

```
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="application/x-ipynb+json">
        <comment>IPython Notebook</comment>
        <glob pattern="*.ipynb"/> 
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then store the file in `~/.local/share/mime` and update the mime database.

```
cp ipynb.xml ~/.local/share/mime
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

#### 2. Create a `jupyter.desktop` file

**Caution:** Edit paths to adapt it to your system and habits.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Jupyter
Icon="$HOME/.icons/jupyter-sq-text.svg"
Exec=/path/to/jupyter notebook %F
Path="$HOME/Documents/Notebooks"
Comment=Jupyter notebook
MimeType=application/x-ipynb+json;
Categories=Science;
Terminal=true
```

Then install the desktop file:

```
desktop-file-install --dir="$HOME/.local/share/applications"  jupyter.desktop
```

#### 3. Add the jupyter icon

I chose the svg version from the design repository of jupyter, and installed in `~/.local/share/icons`

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyter/design/master/logo/svg/jupyter-sq-text.svg -o $HOME/.local/share/icons/jupyter-sq-text.svg
```

Finally, link the mime-type icon to the system:

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/.local/share/icons/jupyter-sq-text.svg /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/application-x-ipynb+json.svg
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/gnome/ -f
```

Hope that's help!

Answer (score 0):

For running Jupyter notebooks, you may prefer the above method.

Whereas for previewing a notebook, I recommend you take a look at [nb-viewer](https://github.com/jithu7432/nb-viewer.git). With it you can preview a Jupyter Notebook with a double click.